# Members of sets related to subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was recently reading about sets and read that $B$ is a subset of $A$ when each member of $B$ is a member of $A$. However, I am not sure about whether this requires the members of $A$ to simply be members of $B$, or if they could be part of $A$ in some other way - i.e. embedded within a set inside $A$.

I tried to think about the following example:

$$X = \{10,\{x\}\}$$
$$Y = \{x\}$$

Does this mean that $Y$ is not a subset of $X$, as $x$ is a member of $Y$, but $x$ is not a member of $X$? If this is the case, I think I could say that $Z = \{\{x\}\}$ is a subset of $X$.

Or, is $Y$ a subset of $X$ as "x" exists somewhere within $X$, even though it is an element of a set, which itself is an element of $X$? I find this unlikely but cannot get past this idea. Thank you.

Comment: $B\subseteq A$ if and only if each element of $B$ is also an element of $A$.   This is different than "each element of $B$ is an element of $A$ or an element of an element of $A$ or ..."  Indeed, in your example $\{x\}\not\subseteq \{10,\{x\}\}$.

Comment: "[does] this requires the members of A to simply be members of B"  Yes. That is what being a member means. "could [they] be part of A ...- i.e. embedded within a set inside A".  No, that embedding is not being a member.  The set in which it is embedded is a member that the element need not be (although it could be coincidentally).  I supposed one can think of $x$ as being "part of" $A$ if $A = \{y, \{x\}\}$ but this being "part of" is not being a member.  $x$ is *not* a member fo $A$.  And a set $B$ is a subset of $A$ is *does* mean that its member are members of $A$.  Nothing else.

Comment: I am very glad your suspicians and intuitions are in the correct side.  The idea that $\{x\}$ might be an element of $A$ but that doesn't mean that $x$ is an element of $A$ is a common stumbling block and intuitive hurdle for too many students.  So you are correct....Please don't be tempted to change your mind... It'd be interesting so define some relation that $x$ is "part" of a set if it is an element of an element (possibly recursively).  But it'd be important to realize that is *NOT* the same as being *IN* the set and to never mistake the two.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer the question. What is $x?$ If $x=10$ then the anser is yes, $Y$ is a subset of $X.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I am not sure about whether this requires the members of $A$ to simply be members of $B$, or if they could be part of $A$ in some other way - i.e. embedded within a set inside $A$."

Former.

> "Does this mean that $Y$ is not a subset of $X$, as $x$ is a member of $Y$, but $x$ is not a member of $X$? If this is the case, I think I could say that $Z = \{\{x\}\}$ is a subset of $X$."

Yes and yes.

> "Or, is $Y$ a subset of $X$ as "x" exists somewhere within $X$, even though it is an element of a set, which itself is an element of $X$?"

**No.**

You can draw a Venn diagram to get a better idea. So, for example, a disk with centre at origin and radius $1$ is a subset of a disk with centre at origin and radius $2.$ For $A$ to be a subset of $B$ it is merely sufficient that $A$ sits inside $B.$ There is no restriction on $B.$

Comment: "Latter"?  Don't you mean former?

Comment: @fleablood Oops. Corrected.

Comment: I was very worried when I read that :)

Comment: @fleablood Let's blame it on lack of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't consider $x$ and $\{x\}$ as the same thing, so $Y\subseteq X$ means $$\forall y\in Y(y\in X)$$